# Google Apps Script - inserting a string in HTML based on if/else statement and based on whether the sheet cell is blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, calendar

```
var ExampleBlank = ss.getSheetByName("Example").getRange(index, 8).isBlank();
if(!ExampleBlank) { "" }
else { "Word" }

var example1 = "blah blah blah"+string(ExampleBlank)+"blah blah blah";
```

Using Google Sheets script to make calendar events.

I have a var (example1) that comprises some HTML and calls on a String (ExampleBlank) which itself goes through an if and else statement.

(example1, the var with HTML is inserted as a description in a calendar event.)

I am using isBlank to check on whether a cell in a specific column (#8) is filled in. If it's blank, then I want the String in "var example1" to return/print out blank. If it's filled in (with anything), I want it to reflect the word "Word".

How do I utilize a string to check on isBlank and output a word?

This only seems to output the word "true" rather than blank vs. "Word".

Comment: That's because the `IsBlank` method is a quick function that literally checks if the cell is blank or not, returning True or False. You can use `if(ss.getSheetByName("Example").getRange(index, 8).isBlank()) { exampleBlank = 'its empty' } else {exampleBlank = ss.getSheetByName("Example").getRange(index, 8).value};`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want the if statement to be blank if indeed the cell turns out to be blank for that row, so that it reflects no word in the HTML of what will be the calendar invite's description. If a cell is indeed filled (with a URL or whatever is detected), then the else statement should be "Filled" but I cannot seem to get that to work with what you've provided. Specifically when changing 'its empty' to just '' and changing the else statement to {exampleBlank = 'filled'}. Also is the ; accidental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var index = 1;

  var middleText;
  if (ss.getSheetByName("Example").getRange(index, 8).isBlank()) {
    middleText = "";
  } else {
    middleText = "something";
  }

  var example1 = "blah blah blah"+middleText+"blah blah blah";
  console.log("example1="+example1);
}
```